# Efficient way to create np array based on values in data frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data frame with N rows containing certain information. Depending on the values in the data frame, I want to create a numpy array with the same number of rows but with M columns.

I have a solution where I iterate through the rows of the data frame and apply a function, which outputs me a row for the array with M entries.

However, I am thinking about whether there are smarter, more efficient ways to avoid iterating through the df?

edit://
Apologies, I think the description might not be really good.
So I have a df with N rows. Depending on the values of certain columns, I want to create M binary entries for each row, that I store in a separate np array.

E.g. the function that I defined can look like this:

```py
def func(row):
    ret = np.zeros(12)
    
    if row['A'] == 'X':
        ret[3] = 1
    else:
        ret[[3,6,9]]=1
    return ret
```

And currently I am applying this (simplified) function to each row of the df to get a full (N,M) array, which seems to be a bit inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

See Pandas [groupby()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to group depending on M and than extract.